# change date format from d/m/Y to Y-m-d

Tags: php, date, datetime

Hello i have date format d/m/Y and i like to change it to Y-m-d.
i use this code:

```
$check_in  = '31/12/2014';
$check_out = '2/01/2015';

$md = explode("/", $check_in); // split the array
$nd = $md[2]."-".$md[1]."-".$md[0]; // join them together
$check_in_new = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($nd));

$mmd = explode("/", $check_out); // split the array
$nnd = $md[2]."-".$mmd[1]."-".$mmd[0]; // join them together
$check_out_new = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($nnd));
```

and its work fine, but if i try to convert 02/01/**2015** (year 2015) the result is **2014**-01-02
its convert the year to **2014**

any help???

Comment: Change `$md[2]` to `$mmd[2]` in the second-to-last line... And read up on `DateTime` objects.

Comment: just a variable mismatch. :(

Comment: Thank you very much it was the problem :)
i appreciate it very much you help me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest utilize `DateTime` class in this case, and provide proper format in it with `createFromFormat`, instead of exploding those strings:

```
$check_in  = '31/12/2014';
$check_out = '2/01/2015';

$check_in_new = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $check_in);
$check_out_new = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $check_out);

echo $check_in_new->format('Y-m-d') . '<br/>';
echo $check_out_new->format('Y-m-d') . '<br/>';
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue the way you are doing right now, you can easily do it by the following way:

```
$check_in  = '31/12/2014';
$check_out = '2/01/2015';
$check_in_new = implode('-',array_reverse(explode('/',$check_in)));
$check_out_new = implode('-',array_reverse(explode('/',$check_out)));
```

But there is a better way to do it:

```
//Set format
$format = 'Y-m-d';
$dto = new DateTime(strtotime($check_in));
$check_in_new = $dto->format($format);
```